# Sorting the array using "sortedArrayUsingSelector" bring records with blank value at top of array

Tags: iphone, sorting, compare

When I sort the array using sortedArrayUsingSelector method , all works fine except it brings records with **BLANK names** at the top of array . I don't want records with BLANK names on top of array instead they should be last in the array. How can I implement this? Here is my code

```
self.tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.tempArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
```

I am sorting the array on first name of user. Here is code of compare method

```
    -(NSComparisonResult)compare:(User*)user {

    return [self.firstName compare:user.firstName];
}
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your comparison method so that you treat empty names differently.

```
-(NSComparisonResult)compare:(User*)user 
{ 
    NSString *selfName;
    NSString *userName;
    if (self.firstName && ![self.firstName isEqualToString:@""])
        selfName = self.firstName;
    else
        selfName = @"zzzzzzzzzz";

    if (user.firstName && ![user.firstName isEqualToString:@""])
        userName = user.firstName;
    else
        userName = @"zzzzzzzzzz";

    return [selfName localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:userName]; 
}
```

You can probably write this in fewer lines of code but I have left it like this for readability. `nil` cannot be used as a comparator for string comparisons.

Currently it is (correctly) sorting blanks to the top, since they are come before populated strings in an alphanumeric sort.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But its not working in any case. Its showing blank records at the top only.

Comment: first names are nil because user didn't enter anything for first name

Comment: Thanks for edit. It is working ,but at the end records are messed up. I mean at the end of array , I have some records whose first name starting with A , E , T, I. Can you tell why this happening?

Comment: Thanks its working . But consider one more case => if first name = 'abc' , then it comes on top before records whose first name starts with a. Can you tell me about this? Again thanks for your answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. The comparison is just string sorting as described in the docs. abc comes before arthur, for example.

Comment: OK. So its not our fault if user enters ',",@ in first name. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Oh right, starts with a ".", not starts with a "a"! yes, nothing you can do about that at this stage, you could restrict when the user enters the name but that's nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Thanks for ur support & answers for my question. Your answers work perfectly as required. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

After getting compare result, You can search for blank username objects in the array and make them to add at last indices.